# How do I name test method correctly

Tags: unit-testing, methods, phpunit

I have one doubt about **How to name test method**, becuase I Lastly have doing unit test to a big project, and based in my experience I think that I am set name test method bad or worse, Here an example about my code.

```
public function notificationApproved(Request $request, User $user) {
    $user              = $user->getId();
    $request           = $request->getRequest();
    $this->notification = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:Notification')->find(Notification::APPROVED);
    $this->notificationCategory    = NotificationCategory::APPROVED;
    $this->notificationStatus      = $this->em->getRepository('AppBundle:NotificationStatus')->find(1);
    $this->reason                  = $reason;
    //notification approvers project
    foreach ($projectHasUserUnits as $keyData => $valueData) {
        $projectUserUnitResponsability = $valueData->getProjectUserUnitResponsability()->last();                                
        $responsability                = $projectUserUnitResponsability->getResponsabilityProject();
        if (is_null($projectUserUnitResponsability->getEndAt()) && ($responsability->getId() == Responsability::TYPE_RESPONSIBLE || $responsability->getId() == Responsability::TYPE_ACCOUNT_MANAGER || $responsability->getId() == Responsability::TYPE_PROJECT_MANAGER)) {
            $user = $valueData->getUserHasUnit()->getUser();
            if( !in_array($user,$this->users)){
                $this->users[] = $user;
                $description_label = 'notification_description_project_50';
                $short_description = 'notification_content_project_50';
                $notification = $this->generateNotification($Project, $user, $description_label,$short_description);
                if ($notification) {
                    $this->notificationTrigger
                                        ->sendProjectNotification($user, $notification, $Project
                                            , $notification->getDescription(), date('l m-d-y H:i a'));
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

it is a big method, I know, but don't worry for its logic, Just see the conditionals, and think how to name a method test like this, In this case, when itself come in all conditionals... maybe:

```
test_notificationApprovedWhenAllConditionsAreTrue
test_notificationApprovedWhenProjectHasUserUnitsIsBiggerThanZeroAndProjectUserUnitResponsabilityGetEndAtIsNotNullAndResponsabilityGetIdIsEqualToResponsabilityTYPERESPONSABILITYorResponsabilityGetIdIsEqualToResponsabilityTYPE_PROJECT_MANAGERanduserInArrayIsTrueAndNotificationIsTrue...
```

You only imagine read that !

However when it come only one conditional is easier that the above, !Of Course!, like this:

```
test_notificationApprovedWhenProjectHasUserUnitsIsBiggerThanZeroAndProjectUserUnitResponsabilityGetEndAtIsNotNullAndResponsabilityGetIdIsEqualToResponsabilityTYPERESPONSABILITYorResponsabilityGetIdIsEqualToResponsabilityTYPE_PROJECT_MANAGER
```

I've tried with comments inside test, but If a test fail, the idea would be guiding for its name (to fix the error rapidly)

So, do you have any idea ?

Answer (score 1):

I have good experience with `given<one-or-more-conditions>_action_result` naming of test methods. Just a simple example for your case:

```
test_givenUserUnitGreaterThanZeroAndProjectIdEqualToOne_whenApproveNotification_thenNotificationIsSent()
```

I've simplified things for the sake of readability but you get the point. This nomenclature is taken from behavior-driven test frameworks. In languages that do not need the `test_` you can save it.

Tests are really good indicators for code quality. Generally speaking if writing unit tests is easy then it's because the code to test is of "good" quality. You can follow some simple guidelines:

- List every precondition exactly as it is necessary for the use case
- Exactly one action. If not make multiple tests.
- Exactly one result. If not extract methods and test them separately.
- If method names get too long because of many preconditions then it might be time to extract a new class because this one has too many responsibilities

Comment: If edited my answer a little bit to make the code quality part a little clearer.

Comment: it is difficult try separate logic, when I don't know logic complexity

Comment: refactoring is a different topic but this naming scheme can be applied nonetheless.

Answer (score 1):

A bit of advice: if you'd add a test annotation, you would not need to prefix  method names with `test`.

```
/**
* @test
*/
function givenThis_producesThat () {
```